# RxJS promise return in transforming function

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs

I play with that https://github.com/corasla/angular2-tackling-state-rxjs . This is implementation of state manager for angular with RxJS from this article https://vsavkin.com/managing-state-in-angular-2-applications-caf78d123d02#.s1otnz6en . I'm wondering how in reducer here https://github.com/corasla/angular2-tackling-state-rxjs/blob/master/src/app/shared/stateAndDispatcher.ts#L92

(fragment of code)

```
function filter(initState: string, actions: Observable<Action>): Observable<string> {
 return actions.scan((state, action) => {
   if (action instanceof SetVisibilityFilter) {
     return action.filter;
   } else {
     return state;
   }
 }, initState);
```

}

make for example request to api and send back to observable that value from request? Returning promise did't solve problem

Edit:
I ty do that:

```
    if (action instanceof SetVisibilityFilter) {
        return new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(()=> action.filter = 'Async', 100));
    } else {
        return state;
    }
```

Comment: Can you show what you tried? I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, I edited question

Comment: You're `Promise` usage doesn't make sense, it needs to resolve at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the same solution of Victor Savkin and worked out 2 concepts for state management with promises:

## Solution 1

I created an additional [action creator](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html#action-creators) to add todos.

**AddTodoAction:**

```
export class AddTodoAction {
    constructor(public todoId: number, public text: string) { }
}
```

**Action creator:**

```
import { AddTodoAction } from './todos.actions';

export function addTodo(text: string) {
    return delay(500).then(() => {
        return new AddTodoAction(Date.now(), text);
    });
}

const delay = (ms: number) =>
    new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

The action creator is just called "addTodo". It returns a Promise and has a delay of 500ms. The delay is a placeholder for the "real" server connection. Later you can replace it with an async call to the server or something like that.

In the component where you injected the dispatcher you have to import this action creator and call the `dispatcher.next` inside `.then`.

**Component:**

```
export class AddTodoComponent {
    constructor( @Inject(dispatcher) private dispatcher: Observer<TodoAction>) { }

    addTodo(input: HTMLInputElement) {
        let value = input.value;
        input.value = '';

        actionCreators.addTodo(value).then(action => {
            this.dispatcher.next(action);
        });
    }
}
```

So now the action creator can make some asynchronous calls to the server. When the action creator resolves the Promise you can use the action that is resolved through the Promise for the dispatcher.

## Solution 2

If you implement the action creators inside a class as a service you can inject the dispatcher there and the action creators are able to dispatch the actions directly.

**Action creator service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class TodoActionCreators {
    constructor( @Inject(dispatcher) private dispatcher: Observer<TodoAction>) { }

    addTodo(text: string) {
        return delay(500).then(() => {
            this.dispatcher.next(new AddTodoAction(Date.now(), text))
        });
    }
}
```

**Component:**

```
export class AddTodoComponent {
    constructor(private todoActionCreators: TodoActionCreators) { }

    addTodo(input: HTMLInputElement) {
        let value = input.value;
        input.value = '';

        this.todoActionCreators.addTodo(value);
    }
}
```

---

### See it working:

*The added todos have a short delay of 500ms.*

[image]

---

### Keep your reducers pure!

In my opinion it is really helpful to add additional action creators to keep the reducers pure. If your reducers are pure they are easy to test without mocking. The action creators handle the async tasks. [Read this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/an-introduction-to-reasonably-pure-functional-programming/) if you need more information about pure functions or the [Redux documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/PrerequisiteConcepts.html).